# Keyboard events to hover/select points in JQplot

Tags: jquery, jqplot, keyboard-events, onkeypress

Is there a way to bind keyboard events to `jqPlot`? I am trying to hover through the points on a plot using only the left and right arrow keys. Also each point should highlight.

I know there are ways to click, double click etc.

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotClick', function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor) {
   if (neighbor) {
   }
});
```

I have also implemented shift click.

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotShiftClick', function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor) {
    if (neighbor) {
    }    
});
```

definition:

```
this.onClick = function(ev) {
    // Event passed in is normalized and will have data attribute.
    // Event passed out is unnormalized.
    if (ev.shiftKey) {
        var positions = getEventPosition(ev);
        var p = ev.data.plot;
        var neighbor = checkIntersection(positions.gridPos, p);
        var evt = jQuery.Event('jqplotShiftClick');
        evt.pageX = ev.pageX;
        evt.pageY = ev.pageY;
        $(this).trigger(evt, [positions.gridPos, positions.dataPos, neighbor, p]);
    } else {
        var positions = getEventPosition(ev);
        var p = ev.data.plot;
        var neighbor = checkIntersection(positions.gridPos, p);
        var evt = jQuery.Event('jqplotClick');
        evt.pageX = ev.pageX;
        evt.pageY = ev.pageY;
        $(this).trigger(evt, [positions.gridPos, positions.dataPos, neighbor, p]);
    }
};​
```

But in all these, there is a click involved. I want to be able to produce the same effect without actually selecting the point.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Just to point out, the only line of code that needs to go inside the if/else is the assignment of the `evt` object. I just used this solution myself to handle shift clicking, but cleaned it up.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to attach/bind the event of `keydown` or `keypress` to the document itself and act upon a key action accordingly.

[This was incorporated into the sample available here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10434535/613495)

*Do not forget to click inside the Result frame in order to use keyboard.*