# How to get the mouse's position in jqPlot

Tags: jquery, graph, mouse, coordinates, jqplot

I would like to write a code that gives the coordinates of the place the user clicks his mouse on a jqPlot graph. Using the option

cursor: {
      show: true,
      tooltipLocation:'sw',
 }

I can SEE the location of the mouse on the graph on the screen. However, I cannot USE it.
Do you know how to get it?

Writing:

$('#chartdiv').bind('jqplotClick',function (event) {

```
 alert( 'The mouse cursor is at ('+event.pageX+','+event.pageY+').');
        }
```

);

gives me the coordinates of the mouse on the whole screen, and if I knew how to get the coordinates of the top left point of the axes of the graph, that would have solved the problem. But I don't manage to do it. Is it possible in jqPlot?

Thank you very much for your help,
and best wishes,
Daphne

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find it using :

```
event.originalEvent.layerX 
event.originalEvent.layerY
```

According to my testing : 
event.pageX and event.pageY gives you coordinates according to the div including your graphic (i.e. graphic + title + offset...).
event.screenX and event.screenY gives you coordinates according to the full screen.
event.originalEvent.layerX and event.originalEvent.layerY gives you coordinates according to only graphic div.

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/q8gfy/3/)

Comment: Dear Anthony,Thank you for that, but it does not seem to work. Can I get the cursor position directly? Can I set the size of the graph (not the chart, which includes also the lables and title) to a specific number of pixels? Thank you, Daphne

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

```
$('#chartdiv').bind('jqplotClick', function(event, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    var x = pointIndex.xaxis;
    var y = pointIndex.yaxis;
});
```

Source: [jqPlot - synchronize cursor across multiple charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783228/jqplot-synchronize-cursor-across-multiple-charts)