# Change the color of dynamical made line when it goes below another line jqplot

Tags: dynamic, colors, jqplot, lines

I have made a jqplot which has one line which is dynamical created from some question and 2 others, an industry standard and a best practices line.

I want to be able to change the color of the dynamical created line when it goes below the industry standard and change it again if it goes above the best practices line.

Is this possible or am I trying to take this too far?

Thank you all in advance for your response.

here is some of my code:

```
//Get radio Values  var values = $('input:radio:checked').map(function () { 
  return this.value; }).get(); 


    var line1 =[[1,values[0]], [2,values[1]], [3,values[2]], [4,values[3]], [5,values[4]]];
var line2 =[[1,4],[2,5],[3,4],[4,5],[5,5]];
var line3 =[[1,1],[2,2],[3,2],[4,4],[5,4]];

  $.jqplot('chartdiv',  [line2,line1,line3],

{  title:'Best Practices Chart',   highlighter: {useAxesFormatters: true,       showTooltip: true,
tooltipLocation: 'nw',
lineWidthAdjust: 2.5, },

grid:{  
drawGridLines: true,
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'},//plot labels   axes:{yaxis:{ticks:['Poor','Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Best Practice'],   renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,


xaxis:{ticks:['DP Officer', 'Policies & Procedures', 'Awareness & Education', 'Information Security', 'Data Quality'],   renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, 

seriesColors: ["#00FF00", "#000000", "#0000FF"],legend: {
        show: true,
      }, series: [

{markerOptions: {style:'dimaond'}, label: 'Best Practise'},
{label: 'Your Practise'},
{markerOptions: {style:'filledSquare'}, label: 'Average Practise'},],
    });
  }); });
```

Answer (score 0):

[The sample presents dynamical redrawing of a series.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/3PNGt/6/)
In the sample after 2 seconds the line at first white gets redrawn to black. You would use it for your redrawing but bare in mind that in doesn't change its default properties and, for example, as in the sample when you press the button the line gets redrawn in default colour.

Comment: The new line you would have to paint yourself on preferably on the same series canvas as your series and you would need to get the points yourself, e.g. by doing intersection between two lines: yours and the horizontal of the grid which marks the good/bad practice. How to paint custom stuff on canvas I showed e.g. [in this sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10434535/613495). Since you will have to do custom painting you can forget about the previous sample and focus on getting the points and checking the sample I added here.

Comment: Hey Boro,Thanks for your quick reply. That was really useful thank you very much but is their a way to change part of the lines color if it goes above or below a certain point. It would be used to highlight a good or bad practice? Thanks again

Comment: This is not one of the simplest problems though I like it (+1 a while ago). I have been experimenting a little with it. [Some of the results you could view in this sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/uBAex/) This shows how you can go about doing what I describe in the comment above. I will be working on it in, at some point in future, but if you manage to solve your problem earlier then please share it with us here. BTW you can easily start working on the sample provided by just forking it.